# Middleware Protected Routes not Detecting Authentication?

Tags: next.js, middleware

My routes in middleware keep redirecting me to the login page despite the user being authenticated. Upon logging in, the user should be redirected to /pages/myprofile. However, it seems that the user is then redirected back to the login page. This also goes for /page/create. Why is the user being redirected back to the login page even after being authenticated?

Middleware.ts

```
export default withAuth({
    pages: {
      signIn: '/pages/login',
    }
  })

export const config = { 
  matcher: [
    "/pages/create",
    "/pages/myprofile",
  ]
};
```

Login Page

```
    const onSubmit = async() => {
        handleUserVisibility()
        if (registerStatus === 'Register') {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                console.log(regData)
                const response = await fetch(`/api/register`,{
                    method: "POST",
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type":"application/json"
                    },
                    body:JSON.stringify(regData)
                });
                signIn('credentials', regData)

                setIsLoading(false)
                toast.success('Registering you');

                
            } catch(error: any) {
                console.log(error.response.data)
                toast.error(error.response.data)
            }

        } else if (registerStatus ==='Login') {
            
            console.log(logData)
            setIsLoading(true)
            signIn('credentials', {
                ...logData,
                redirect: false
            })
            .then((callback) => {
                if (callback?.error) {
                    toast.error('Invalid credentials');
                }

                if (callback?.ok && !callback?.error) {
                    toast.success('Logged in');
                    console.log(session?.status)
                    window.location.href=`/pages/myprofile`
                }
            })

            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
        }

    }
    useEffect(() => {

        console.log(session?.status)

        if (session?.status==='authenticated') {
            console.log('Authenticated')
            window.location.href=`/pages/myprofile`
        }
    }, [session?.status])
```